# i run code for artificial neural network visualization but "AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'core' "

Tags: python

code to visualize ann

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy
import seaborn as sns
import openpyxl
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\This Pc\Downloads\ckd.xlsx')
X = df.drop('Class', axis=1)
Y= df['Class']
EN = LabelEncoder()
EN.fit(Y)
Y = EN.transform(Y)
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6,activation="relu"))       //input/hidden layer 1
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=6,activation="relu"))       // input hidden layer2
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4,activation="softmax"))    //output layer
ann.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])
ann.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=32,epochs = 100)
from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz;
ann_viz(ann, title="My first neural network")       // visualize ann
```

Comment: Please format code. Can you produce a minimal example showing this error and the line it occurs on? I think it might be a version compatibility issue - in which case showing the versions may be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.